# Regarding Uniform Acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, kinematics, acceleration

Please give some basic intuition or hint to solve this question. I'm getting stuck.

> The star of a distant solar system explodes as a supernova. At the moment of the explosion, a
> resting exploration spaceship is 15 AU away from the shock wave. The shock wave of the explosion travels with 25000 km/s towards the spaceship. To save the crew, the spacecraft makes use
> of a special booster that uniformly accelerates at 150 m/s2
> in the opposite direction. Determine if the crew manages to escape from the shock wave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have equations for motion with constant acceleration, specifically one which gives position given time, initial position, initial velocity, and acceleration. In this problem, you have two moving objects: the spaceship and the shock wave. These two objects will each have their own different equations of motion. The ship is doomed if there is any time when the position of the shock wave and the position of the ship are at the same location at the same time.

Comment: so should I find out the distance covered by each in a fixed interval of time, then for the next same interval of time and if the distance between them is getting larger after every time interval, is it safe to say that the spacecraft is safe?

Comment: Also, isn't it kinda obvious that an accelerating body will always escape a body moving with constant velocity. Is there any example of a the other outcome?

Comment: @DaudAli Sure, a body with a higher acceleration will pass a body with a constant velocity *eventually*. But, in this problem, the shock wave may reach the ship before the ship has accelerated enough to be going faster than the shock wave.